# Listview, OGG audio file stops working

Tags: android, listview, media-player

Hello, Everybody. I have a listview with 100 items. Each item is clickable and then opens a specific .ogg audio file. So far, so good. But, after ten, eleven clicks over the items, suddenly, the .ogg audio file doesn't work....no audio is playing anymore. Could someone help me?

This is an excerpt from my code that I'm using:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
long arg3) {


if ("Howl".equals(text[position])) {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.howl);
    player.start();


   }


if ("Meow".equals(text[position])) {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.meow);
    player.start();
```

}

```
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

put this in the onCreate

```
voice.setOnCompletionListener( new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        public void onCompletion( MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            mp.release();

        }
    });
```